# Returns of multiple stocks using pandas at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have close prices of multiple stocks over multiple days in a dataframe like this.

```
In [67]: df
Out[67]:
          Date Symbol   Close
0   12/30/2016   AMZN  749.87
1   12/29/2016   AMZN  765.15
2   12/28/2016   AMZN  772.13
3   12/27/2016   AMZN  771.40
4   12/30/2016  GOOGL  792.45
5   12/29/2016  GOOGL  802.88
6   12/28/2016  GOOGL  804.57
7   12/27/2016  GOOGL  805.80
8   12/30/2016   NFLX  123.80
9   12/29/2016   NFLX  125.33
10  12/28/2016   NFLX  125.89
11  12/27/2016   NFLX  128.35
```

I would like to compute daily returns of these stocks using pandas. The output should looks like this:

```
         Date Symbol     Return
0   12/27/2016   AMZN       NaN
1   12/28/2016   AMZN  0.000946
2   12/29/2016   AMZN -0.009040
3   12/30/2016   AMZN -0.019970
4   12/27/2016  GOOGL       NaN
5   12/28/2016  GOOGL -0.001526
6   12/29/2016  GOOGL -0.002101
7   12/30/2016  GOOGL -0.012991
8   12/27/2016   NFLX       NaN
9   12/28/2016   NFLX -0.019166
10  12/29/2016   NFLX -0.004448
11  12/30/2016   NFLX -0.012208
```

I got the above output using following code but I feel this can be simplified further.

```
In [70]: rtn = df.pivot("Date", "Symbol", "Close").pct_change().reset_index()
In [73]: pd.melt(rtn, id_vars='Date', value_vars=list(rtn.columns[1:]),var_name='Symbol',value_name='Return')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['Symbol','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Return'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].pct_change()
print (df)
          Date Symbol   Close    Return
0   12/27/2016   AMZN  771.40       NaN
1   12/28/2016   AMZN  772.13  0.000946
2   12/29/2016   AMZN  765.15 -0.009040
3   12/30/2016   AMZN  749.87 -0.019970
4   12/27/2016  GOOGL  805.80       NaN
5   12/28/2016  GOOGL  804.57 -0.001526
6   12/29/2016  GOOGL  802.88 -0.002101
7   12/30/2016  GOOGL  792.45 -0.012991
8   12/27/2016   NFLX  128.35       NaN
9   12/28/2016   NFLX  125.89 -0.019166
10  12/29/2016   NFLX  125.33 -0.004448
11  12/30/2016   NFLX  123.80 -0.012208
```

Comment: There is a bug (pandas.0.23.0), see here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21200 Work around : df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())

Comment: @TChi - Use [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21200#issuecomment-401141250). Or upgrade, in pandas 0.25.0 working nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can `set_index` and `unstack` which will sort your index for you and then `pct_change` and `stack` back.

```
print(
    df.set_index(['Date', 'Symbol'])
      .Close.unstack().pct_change()
      .stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='Return')
      .sort_values(['Symbol', 'Date'])
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)


         Date Symbol    Return
0  2016-12-27   AMZN       NaN
1  2016-12-28   AMZN  0.000946
2  2016-12-29   AMZN -0.009040
3  2016-12-30   AMZN -0.019970
4  2016-12-27  GOOGL       NaN
5  2016-12-28  GOOGL -0.001526
6  2016-12-29  GOOGL -0.002101
7  2016-12-30  GOOGL -0.012991
8  2016-12-27   NFLX       NaN
9  2016-12-28   NFLX -0.019166
10 2016-12-29   NFLX -0.004448
11 2016-12-30   NFLX -0.012208
```

Comment: `stack(dropna=False)`